# Highlight borders of the nation

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, openstreetmap

When I search for a country I would like the borders to be highlighted on the map.

I don't know how to do with openstreetmap , leaflet and react

Demo: [Countries App](https://gentle-vacherin-eaf06f.netlify.app/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be much help but I have done something similar in which I highlighted the selected country. I used html, css, js + jQuery with php. Had to cut out the rest of the geojson data but you can see the idea hopefully.

Live site - [www.owenkane.co.uk/project1](http://www.owenkane.co.uk/project1)
If you want to see an idea of what I have managed.

PHP

```
<?php

$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

$countryInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents("../assets/countryBorders.geo.json"), true);

foreach ($countryInfo['features'] as $country) {
    if ($country['properties']['iso_a2'] == $_REQUEST['countryCode']) {
        $borders = $country['geometry'];
    }
}

$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
$output['data'] = $borders;

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($output['data']); 



?>
```

JS

```
function getCountryBorders(countryCode) {

$.ajax({
    url: "libs/php/getCountryBorders.php",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        countryCode,
    },
    success: function (result) {
        borders = result.coordinates;
        // highlight country on map
        const myStyle = {
            "color": "#ff7800",
            "weight": 5,
            "opacity": 0.65
        };
        const myLines = result;

        highlight.addData(myLines, {
            style: myStyle
        });

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("get border error");
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
})
```

}

geojson data

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Bahamas","iso_a2":"BS","iso_a3":"BHS","iso_n3":"044"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-77.53466,23.75975],[-77.78,23.71],[-78.03405,24.28615],[-78.40848,24.57564],[-78.19087,25.2103],[-77.89,25.17],[-77.54,24.34],[-77.53466,23.75975]]],[[[-77.82,26.58],[-78.91,26.42],[-78.98,26.79],[-78.51,26.87],[-77.85,26.84],[-77.82,26.58]]],[[[-77,26.59],[-77.17255,25.87918],[-77.35641,26.00735],[-77.34,26.53],[-77.78802,26.92516],[-77.79,27.04],[-77,26.59]]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Canada","iso_a2":"CA","iso_a3":"CAN","iso_n3":"124"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-63.6645,46.55001],[-62.9393,46.41587],[-62.01208,46.44314],[-62.50391,46.03339],[-62.87433,45.96818],[-64.1428,46.39265],[-64.39261,46.72747],[-64.01486,47.03601],[-63.6645,46.55001]]],[[[-61.806305,49.10506],[-62.29318,49.08717],[-63.58926,49.40069],[-64.51912,49.87304],[-64.17322,49.95718],[-62.85829,49.70641],[-61.835585,49.28855],[-61.806305,49.10506]]],[[[-123.51000158755114,48.51001089130344],[-124.0128907883995,48.370846259141416],[-125.65501277733837,48.8250045843385],[-125.95499446679275,49.179995835967645],[-126.85000443587187,49.53000031188043],[-127.0299934495444,49.81499583597008],[-128.05933630436624,49.9949590114266],[-128.44458410710217,50.539137681676124],[-128.35841365625544,50.770648098343685],[-127.3085810960299,50.55257355407195],[-126.69500097721232,50.400903225295394],[-125.75500667382319,50.29501821552938],[-125.4150015875588,49.95000051533261],[-124.92076818911934,49.475274970083404],[-123.92250870832102,49.06248362893581],[-123.51000158755114,48.51001089130344]]],[[[-56.13403581401712,50.6870097926793],[-56.795881720595276,49.81230866149096],[-56.1431050278843,50.150117499382844],[-55.471492275602934,49.93581533466846],[-55.82240108908093,49.58712860777911],[-54.935142584845664,49.31301097268684],[-54.47377539734378,49.55669118915918],[-53.476549445191324,49.24913890237405],[-53.78601375997124,48.51678050393363],[-53.086133999226256,48.687803656603535],[-52.958648240762244,48.157164211614486],[-52.64809872090419,47.5355484075755],[-53.069158291218336,46.65549876564495],[-53.52145626485304,46.61829173439483],[-54.17893551290254,46.80706574155701],[-53.961868659060485,47.62520701760192],[-54.24048214376214,47.75227936460763],[-55.4007730780115,46.884993801453135],[-55.99748084168584,46.9197203639533],[-55.29121904155278,47.389562486351],[-56.25079871278052,47.63254507098739],[-57.3252292547771,47.572807115258],[-59.26601518414677,47.603347886742505],[-59.419494188053704,47.899453843774864],[-58.796586473207405,48.25152537697949],[-59.231624518456535,48.52318838153781],[-58.39180497906523,49.12558055276418],[-57.35868974468604,50.718274034215845],[-56.73865007183201,51.28743825947853],[-55.870976935435294,51.632094224649194],[-55.406974249886616,51.58827261006573],[-55.60021826844209,51.31707469339793],[-56.13403581401712,50.6870097926793]]],[[[-133.1800040417117,54.16997549093531],[-132.71000788443132,54.040009315423525],[-131.74998958400326,54.12000438090922],[-132.049480347351,52.984621487024526],[-131.1790425218266,52.180432847698285],[-131.57782954982292,52.18237071390925],[-132.18042842677855,52.639707139692405],[-132.54999243231387,53.100014960332146],[-133.05461117875552,53.41146881775537],[-133.2396644827927,53.8510802272624],[-133.1800040417117,54.16997549093531]]],[[[-79.26582,62.158675],[-79.65752,61.63308],[-80.09956,61.7181],[-80.36215,62.01649],[-80.315395,62.085565],[-79.92939,62.3856],[-79.52002,62.36371],[-79.26582,62.158675]]],[[[-81.89825,62.7108],[-83.06857,62.15922],[-83.77462,62.18231],[-83.99367,62.4528],[-83.25048,62.91409],[-81.87699,62.90458],[-81.89825,62.7108]]],[[[-85.16130794954985,65.65728465439281],[-84.97576371940596,65.217518215589],[-84.4640120104195,65.37177236598018],[-83.88262630891975,65.10961782496355],[-82.78757687043877,64.76669302027469],[-81.64201371939254,64.45513580998696],[-81.55344031444425,63.979609280037145],[-80.81736121287886,64.05748566350101],[-80.10345130076661,63.725981350348604],[-80.99101986359568,63.41124603947497],[-82.54717810741701,63.65172231714524],[-83.10879757356506,64.10187571883972],[-84.10041663281388,63.56971181909802],[-85.52340471061902,63.05237905542409],[-85.86676876498237,63.637252916103556],[-87.22198320183674,63.541238104905226],[-86.35275977247127,64.03583323837071],[-86.22488644076513,64.82291697860826],[-85.88384782585487,65.73877838811705],[-85.16130794954985,65.65728465439281]]],[[[-75.86588,67.14886],[-76.98687,67.09873],[-77.2364,67.58809],[-76.81166,68.14856],[-75.89521,68.28721],[-75.1145,68.01036],[-75.10333,67.58202],[-75.21597,67.44425],[-75.86588,67.14886]]],[[[-95.64768120380052,69.10769035832178],[-96.2695212038006,68.75704035832175],[-97.61740120380057,69.0600303583218],[-98.43180120380052,68.9507003583218],[-99.79740120380053,69.4000303583218],[-98.91740120380055,69.7100303583218],[-98.2182612038005,70.14354035832176],[-97.15740120380056,69.86003035832181],[-96.55740120380054,69.68003035832176],[-96.25740120380053,69.49003035832177],[-95.64768120380052,69.10769035832178]]],[[[-90.5471,69.49766],[-90.55151,68.47499],[-89.21515,69.25873],[-88.01966,68.61508],[-88.31749,67.87338],[-87.35017,67.19872],[-86.30607,67.92146],[-85.57664,68.78456],[-85.52197,69.88211],[-84.10081,69.80539],[-82.62258,69.65826],[-81.28043,69.16202],[-81.2202,68.66567],[-81.96436,68.13253],[-81.25928,67.59716],[-81.38653,67.11078],[-83.34456,66.41154],[-84.73542,66.2573],[-85.76943,66.55833],[-86.0676,66.05625],[-87.03143,65.21297],[-87.32324,64.77563],[-88.48296,64.09897],[-89.91444,64.03273],[-90.70398,63.61017],[-90.77004,62.96021],[-91.93342,62.83508],[-93.15698,62.02469],[-94.24153,60.89865],[-94.62931,60.11021],[-94.6846,58.94882],[-93.21502,58.78212],[-92.76462,57.84571],[-92.29703,57.08709],[-90.89769,57.28468],[-89.03953,56.85172],[-88.03978,56.47162],[-87.32421,55.99914],[-86.07121,55.72383],[-85.01181,55.3026],[-83.36055,55.24489],[-82.27285,55.14832],[-82.4362,54.28227],[-82.12502,53.27703],[-81.40075,52.15788],[-79.91289,51.20842],[-79.14301,51.53393],[-78.60191,52.56208],[-79.12421,54.14145],[-79.82958,54.66772],[-78.22874,55.13645],[-77.0956,55.83741],[-76.54137,56.53423],[-76.62319,57.20263],[-77.30226,58.05209],[-78.51688,58.80458],[-77.33676,59.85261],[-77.77272,60.75788],[-78.10687,62.31964],[-77.41067,62.55053],[-75.69621,62.2784],[-74.6682,62.18111],[-73.83988,62.4438],[-72.90853,62.10507],[-71.67708,61.52535],[-71.37369,61.13717],[-69.59042,61.06141],[-69.62033,60.22125],[-69.2879,58.95736],[-68.37455,58.80106],[-67.64976,58.21206],[-66.20178,58.76731],[-65.24517,59.87071],[-64.58352,60.33558],[-63.80475,59.4426],[-62.50236,58.16708],[-61.39655,56.96745],[-61.79866,56.33945],[-60.46853,55.77548],[-59.56962,55.20407],[-57.97508,54.94549],[-57.3332,54.6265],[-56.93689,53.78032],[-56.15811,53.64749],[-55.75632,53.27036],[-55.68338,52.14664],[-56.40916,51.7707],[-57.12691,51.41972],[-58.77482,51.0643],[-60.03309,50.24277],[-61.72366,50.08046],[-63.86251,50.29099],[-65.36331,50.2982],[-66.39905,50.22897],[-67.23631,49.51156],[-68.51114,49.06836],[-69.95362,47.74488],[-71.10458,46.82171],[-70.25522,46.98606],[-68.65,48.3],[-66.55243,49.1331],[-65.05626,49.23278],[-64.17099,48.74248],[-65.11545,48.07085],[-64.79854,46.99297],[-64.47219,46.23849],[-63.17329,45.73902],[-61.52072,45.88377],[-60.51815,47.00793],[-60.4486,46.28264],[-59.80287,45.9204],[-61.03988,45.26525],[-63.25471,44.67014],[-64.24656,44.26553],[-65.36406,43.54523],[-66.1234,43.61867],[-66.16173,44.46512],[-64.42549,45.29204],[-66.02605,45.25931],[-67.13741,45.13753],[-67.79134,45.70281],[-67.79046,47.06636],[-68.23444,47.35486],[-68.905,47.185],[-69.237216,47.447781],[-69.99997,46.69307],[-70.305,45.915],[-70.66,45.46],[-71.08482,45.30524],[-71.405,45.255],[-71.50506,45.0082],[-73.34783,45.00738],[-74.867,45.00048],[-75.31821,44.81645],[-76.375,44.09631],[-76.5,44.01845889375872],[-76.82003414580558,43.628784288093755],[-77.7378850979577,43.629055589363304],[-78.72027991404238,43.625089423184875],[-79.17167355011188,43.46633942318422],[-79.01,43.27],[-78.92,42.965],[-78.9393621487437,42.86361135514804],[-80.24744767934794,42.36619985612259],[-81.27774654816716,42.20902598730686],[-82.43927771679162,41.675105088867156],[-82.69008928092018,41.675105088867156],[-83.02981014680694,41.83279572200584],[-83.14199968131256,41.975681057292825],[-83.12,42.08],[-82.9,42.43],[-82.43,42.98],[-82.1376423815039,43.571087551439916],[-82.33776312543108,44.44],[-82.55092464875818,45.347516587905375],[-83.59285071484308,45.81689362241237],[-83.46955074739463,45.99468638771259],[-83.61613094759059,46.11692698829907],[-83.89076534700575,46.11692698829907],[-84.09185126416148,46.275418606138174],[-84.14211951367338,46.51222585711574],[-84.3367,46.40877],[-84.6049,46.4396],[-84.54374874544587,46.538684190449146],[-84.77923824739992,46.637101955749046],[-84.87607988151485,46.90008331968238],[-85.65236324740343,47.22021881773051],[-86.46199083122826,47.55333801939204],[-87.43979262330024,47.94],[-88.37811418328673,48.302917588893735],[-89.27291744663668,48.019808254582664],[-89.6,48.01],[-90.83,48.27],[-91.64,48.14],[-92.61,48.45],[-93.63087,48.60926],[-94.32914,48.67074],[-94.64,48.84],[-94.81758,49.38905],[-95.15609,49.38425],[-95.15906950917204,49],[-97.22872000000481,49.0007],[-100.65,49],[-104.04826,48.99986],[-107.05,49],[-110.05,49],[-113,49],[-116.04818,49],[-117.03121,49],[-120,49],[-122.84,49],[-122.97421,49.0025377777778],[-124.91024,49.98456],[-125.62461,50.41656],[-127.43561,50.83061],[-127.99276,51.71583],[-127.85032,52.32961],[-129.12979,52.75538],[-129.30523,53.56159],[-130.51497,54.28757],[-130.53611,54.80278],[-129.98,55.285],[-130.00778,55.91583],[-131.70781,56.55212],[-132.73042,57.69289],[-133.35556,58.41028],[-134.27111,58.86111],[-134.945,59.27056],[-135.47583,59.78778],[-136.47972,59.46389],[-137.4525,58.905],[-138.34089,59.56211],[-139.039,60],[-140.013,60.27682],[-140.99778,60.30639],[-140.9925,66.00003],[-140.986,69.712],[-139.12052,69.47102],[-137.54636,68.99002],[-136.50358,68.89804],[-135.62576,69.31512],[-134.41464,69.62743],[-132.92925,69.50534],[-131.43136,69.94451],[-129.79471,70.19369],[-129.10773,69.77927],[-128.36156,70.01286],[-128.13817,70.48384],[-127.44712,70.37721],[-125.75632,69.48058],[-124.42483,70.1584],[-124.28968,69.39969],[-123.06108,69.56372],[-122.6835,69.85553],[-121.47226,69.79778],[-119.94288,69.37786],[-117.60268,69.01128],[-116.22643,68.84151],[-115.2469,68.90591],[-113.89794,68.3989],[-115.30489,67.90261],[-113.49727,67.68815],[-110.798,67.80612],[-109.94619,67.98104],[-108.8802,67.38144],[-107.79239,67.88736],[-108.81299,68.31164],[-108.16721,68.65392],[-106.95,68.7],[-106.15,68.8],[-105.34282,68.56122],[-104.33791,68.018],[-103.22115,68.09775],[-101.45433,67.64689],[-99.90195,67.80566],[-98.4432,67.78165],[-98.5586,68.40394],[-97.66948,68.57864],[-96.11991,68.23939],[-96.12588,67.29338],[-95.48943,68.0907],[-94.685,68.06383],[-94.23282,69.06903],[-95.30408,69.68571],[-96.47131,70.08976],[-96.39115,71.19482],[-95.2088,71.92053],[-93.88997,71.76015],[-92.87818,71.31869],[-91.51964,70.19129],[-92.40692,69.69997],[-90.5471,69.49766]]],[[[-114.1671699999999,73.12145],[-114.66634,72.65277],[-112.44101999999988,72.95540000000011],[-111.05039,72.4504],[-109.92034999999989,72.96113],[-109.00654,72.63335],[-108.18835,71.65089],[-107.68599,72.06548],[-108.39639,73.08953000000011],[-107.51645,73.23598],[-106.52259,73.07601],[-105.40246,72.67259],[-104.77484,71.6984],[-104.46475999999984,70.99297],[-102.78537,70.49776],[-100.9807799999999,70.02432],[-101.08929,69.58447000000012],[-102.73116,69.50402],[-102.09329,69.11962000000011],[-102.43024,68.75282],[-104.24,68.91],[-105.96,69.18000000000015],[-107.12254,69.11922],[-109,68.78],[-111.53414887520013,68.63005915681794],[-113.3132,68.53554],[-113.85495999999983,69.00744000000012],[-115.22,69.28],[-116.10794,69.16821],[-117.34,69.96000000000012],[-116.67472999999988,70.06655],[-115.13112,70.2373],[-113.72141,70.19237],[-112.4161,70.36638],[-114.35,70.6],[-116.48684,70.52045],[-117.9048,70.54056000000014],[-118.43238,70.9092],[-116.11311,71.30918],[-117.65568,71.2952],[-119.40199,71.55859],[-118.56267,72.30785],[-117.86642,72.70594],[-115.18909,73.31459000000012],[-114.1671699999999,73.12145]]],[[[-104.5,73.42],[-105.38,72.76],[-106.94,73.46],[-106.6,73.6],[-105.26,73.64],[-104.5,73.42]]],[[[-76.34,73.10268498995302],[-76.25140380859375,72.82638549804688],[-77.31443786621091,72.85554504394527],[-78.39167022705081,72.87665557861328],[-79.48625183105466,72.74220275878909],[-79.77583312988284,72.80290222167974],[-80.87609863281253,73.3331832885742],[-80.83388519287105,73.69318389892578],[-80.35305786132812,73.75971984863278],[-78.06443786621094,73.65193176269534],[-76.34,73.10268498995302]]],[[[-86.56217851433414,73.15744700793846],[-85.77437130404454,72.53412588163383],[-84.85011247428824,73.34027822538712],[-82.31559017610098,73.75095083281059],[-80.60008765330764,72.71654368762421],[-80.7489416165244,72.06190664335077],[-78.77063859731078,72.35217316353416],[-77.82462398955958,72.74961660429105],[-75.60584469267573,72.24367849393741],[-74.22861609566499,71.7671442735579],[-74.09914079455771,71.33084015571765],[-72.24222571479766,71.5569245469945],[-71.20001542833519,70.92001251899723],[-68.7860542466849,70.52502370877426],[-67.91497046575694,70.12194753689761],[-66.96903337265417,69.18608734809189],[-68.80512285020055,68.72019847276442],[-66.44986609563387,68.06716339789202],[-64.86231441919522,67.84753856065163],[-63.42493445499676,66.92847321234066],[-61.85198137068058,66.86212067327784],[-62.1631768459423,66.16025136988961],[-63.918444383384184,64.99866852483284],[-65.14886023625363,65.42603261988668],[-66.72121904159854,66.3880410834322],[-68.01501603867396,66.26272573512439],[-68.14128740097917,65.68978913030438],[-67.08964616562339,65.108455105237],[-65.73208045109976,64.64840566675863],[-65.32016760930128,64.38273712834606],[-64.66940629744968,63.39292674422748],[-65.01380388045891,62.67418508569599],[-66.27504472519047,62.945098781986076],[-68.78318620469273,63.74567007105181],[-67.36968075221304,62.883965562584876],[-66.3282972886672,62.280074774822054],[-66.16556820338016,61.93089712182589],[-68.87736650254465,62.33014923771282],[-71.02343705919384,62.91070811629584],[-72.235378587519,63.39783600529517],[-71.8862784491713,63.67998932560885],[-73.37830624051838,64.19396312118383],[-74.8344189114226,64.67907562932379],[-74.81850257027673,64.38909332951798],[-77.70997982452005,64.22954234481679],[-78.55594885935417,64.57290639918014],[-77.89728105336192,65.30919220647479],[-76.0182742987972,65.32696889918316],[-73.95979529488272,65.45476471624089],[-74.29388342964964,65.8117713487294],[-73.94491248238265,66.31057811142672],[-72.65116716173941,67.28457550726387],[-72.92605994331609,67.72692576768239],[-73.31161780464575,68.06943716091291],[-74.84330725777681,68.55462718370129],[-76.86910091826674,68.89473562283027],[-76.22864905465735,69.14776927354742],[-77.28736996123712,69.76954010688328],[-78.1686339993266,69.82648753526891],[-78.95724219431673,70.16688019477542],[-79.49245500356366,69.87180776638891],[-81.30547095409176,69.74318512641435],[-84.94470618359847,69.9666340196444],[-87.06000342481789,70.26000112576537],[-88.6817132230015,70.41074127876081],[-89.51341956252304,70.76203766548099],[-88.46772111688075,71.21818553332133],[-89.8881512112875,71.22255219184996],[-90.20516028518202,72.2350743679608],[-89.43657670770494,73.12946421985237],[-88.40824154331281,73.53788890247121],[-85.82615108920092,73.80381582304521],[-86.56217851433414,73.15744700793846]]],[[[-100.35642,73.84389],[-99.16387,73.63339],[-97.38,73.76],[-97.12,73.47],[-98.05359,72.99052],[-96.54,72.56],[-96.72,71.66],[-98.35966,71.27285],[-99.32286,71.35639],[-100.01482,71.73827],[-102.5,72.51],[-102.48,72.83],[-100.43836,72.70588],[-101.54,73.36],[-100.35642,73.84389]]],[[[-93.19629553910022,72.77199249947336],[-94.26904659704726,72.02459625923598],[-95.40985551632266,72.06188080513459],[-96.03374508338246,72.94027680123182],[-96.01826799191099,73.4374299180958],[-95.49579342322403,73.86241689726418],[-94.50365759965234,74.1349067247392],[-92.42001217321177,74.10002513294219],[-90.50979285354259,73.85673248971203],[-92.0039652168299,72.9662442084585],[-93.19629553910022,72.77199249947336]]],[[[-120.46,71.38360179308759],[-123.09219,70.90164],[-123.62,71.34],[-125.92894873747335,71.86868846301141],[-125.5,72.29226081179502],[-124.80729,73.02256],[-123.9399999999999,73.68000000000015],[-124.91775,74.29275000000013],[-121.53788,74.44893],[-120.10978,74.24135],[-117.55563999999987,74.18577],[-116.58442,73.89607],[-115.51081,73.47519],[-116.76793999999988,73.22292],[-119.22,72.52],[-120.46,71.82],[-120.46,71.38360179308759]]],[[[-93.61275590694049,74.97999726022445],[-94.15690873897384,74.59234650338686],[-95.60868058956561,74.66686391875177],[-96.82093217648458,74.92762319609658],[-96.2885874092298,75.37782827422335],[-94.85081987178913,75.6472175157609],[-93.97774654821794,75.29648956979597],[-93.61275590694049,74.97999726022445]]],[[[-98.5,76.72],[-97.735585,76.25656],[-97.704415,75.74344],[-98.16,75],[-99.80874,74.89744],[-100.88366,75.05736],[-100.86292,75.64075],[-102.50209,75.5638],[-102.56552,76.3366],[-101.48973,76.30537],[-99.98349,76.64634],[-98.57699,76.58859],[-98.5,76.72]]],[[[-108.21141,76.20168],[-107.81943,75.84552],[-106.92893,76.01282],[-105.881,75.9694],[-105.70498,75.47951],[-106.31347,75.00527],[-109.7,74.85],[-112.22307,74.41696],[-113.74381,74.39427],[-113.87135,74.72029],[-111.79421,75.1625],[-116.31221,75.04343],[-117.7104,75.2222],[-116.34602,76.19903],[-115.40487,76.47887],[-112.59056,76.14134],[-110.81422,75.54919],[-109.0671,75.47321],[-110.49726,76.42982],[-109.5811,76.79417],[-108.54859,76.67832],[-108.21141,76.20168]]],[[[-94.68408586299947,77.09787832305838],[-93.57392106807313,76.77629588490609],[-91.60502315953661,76.77851797149461],[-90.74184587274922,76.44959747995681],[-90.96966142450799,76.07401317005946],[-89.82223792189927,75.84777374948563],[-89.18708289259979,75.61016551380763],[-87.83827633334963,75.56618886992723],[-86.37919226758868,75.48242137318218],[-84.78962521029061,75.69920400664651],[-82.75344458691006,75.78431509063125],[-81.12853084992437,75.71398346628203],[-80.05751095245915,75.33684886341588],[-79.83393286814832,74.92312734648719],[-80.45777075877584,74.65730377877779],[-81.94884253612554,74.44245901152433],[-83.22889360221143,74.56402781849096],[-86.0974523587333,74.41003205026115],[-88.15035030796022,74.39230703398499],[-89.76472205275837,74.51555532500115],[-92.42244096552943,74.837757880341],[-92.7682854886428,75.38681997344216],[-92.88990597204173,75.88265534128266],[-93.893824022176,76.31924367950054],[-95.96245744503582,76.44138092722247],[-97.12137895382949,76.75107778594761],[-96.74512285031236,77.16138865834515],[-94.68408586299947,77.09787832305838]]],[[[-116.19858659550734,77.64528677032621],[-116.33581336145838,76.87696157501055],[-117.10605058476878,76.53003184681913],[-118.04041215703813,76.4811717800871],[-119.89931758688569,76.05321340606199],[-121.4999950771265,75.9000186225328],[-122.85492448615896,76.11654287383568],[-122.8549252936032,76.11654287383568],[-121.15753536032825,76.86450755482835],[-119.10393897182104,77.51221995717464],[-117.57013078496597,77.4983189968881],[-116.19858659550734,77.64528677032621]]],[[[-93.84000301794399,77.5199972602345],[-94.29560828324526,77.4913426785287],[-96.16965410031008,77.5551113959769],[-96.43630449093612,77.83462921824362],[-94.42257727738638,77.82000478790499],[-93.72065629756588,77.63433136668033],[-93.84000301794399,77.5199972602345]]],[[[-110.18693803591297,77.6970148790503],[-112.05119116905848,77.40922882761686],[-113.53427893761906,77.73220652944116],[-112.72458675825384,78.05105011668195],[-111.26444332563085,78.15295604116156],[-109.8544518705471,77.99632477488484],[-110.18693803591297,77.6970148790503]]],[[[-109.66314571820259,78.60197256134569],[-110.88131425661886,78.40691986766001],[-112.54209143761517,78.4079017198735],[-112.5258908760916,78.55055451121522],[-111.5000103422334,78.84999359813057],[-110.96366065147602,78.80444082306522],[-109.66314571820259,78.60197256134569]]],[[[-95.83029496944934,78.05694122996326],[-97.30984290239799,77.85059723582178],[-98.12428931353396,78.08285696075758],[-98.55286780474664,78.4581053738451],[-98.63198442258552,78.87193024363839],[-97.33723141151262,78.83198436147677],[-96.75439876990879,78.765812689927],[-95.55927792029458,78.41831452098029],[-95.83029496944934,78.05694122996326]]],[[[-100.06019182005214,78.3247543403159],[-99.67093909381362,77.9075446642074],[-101.30394019245301,78.01898489044481],[-102.94980872273305,78.34322866486022],[-105.17613277873154,78.38033234324574],[-104.21042945027716,78.6774201524918],[-105.41958045125854,78.91833567983645],[-105.49228919149316,79.30159393992919],[-103.52928239623793,79.16534902619165],[-100.82515804726881,78.80046173777869],[-100.06019182005214,78.3247543403159]]],[[[-87.02,79.66],[-85.81435,79.3369],[-87.18756,79.0393],[-89.03535,78.28723],[-90.80436,78.21533],[-92.87669,78.34333],[-93.95116,78.75099],[-93.93574,79.11373],[-93.14524,79.3801],[-94.974,79.37248],[-96.07614,79.70502],[-96.70972,80.15777],[-96.01644,80.60233],[-95.32345,80.90729],[-94.29843,80.97727],[-94.73542,81.20646],[-92.40984,81.25739],[-91.13289,80.72345],[-89.45,80.50932203389829],[-87.81,80.32],[-87.02,79.66]]],[[[-68.5,83.10632151676575],[-65.82735,83.02801],[-63.68,82.9],[-61.85,82.6286],[-61.89388,82.36165],[-64.334,81.92775],[-66.75342,81.72527],[-67.65755,81.50141],[-65.48031,81.50657],[-67.84,80.9],[-69.4697,80.61683],[-71.18,79.8],[-73.2428,79.63415],[-73.88,79.43016220480207],[-76.90773,79.32309],[-75.52924,79.19766],[-76.22046,79.01907],[-75.39345,78.52581],[-76.34354,78.18296],[-77.88851,77.89991],[-78.36269,77.50859],[-79.75951,77.20968],[-79.61965,76.98336],[-77.91089,77.022045],[-77.88911,76.777955],[-80.56125,76.17812],[-83.17439,76.45403],[-86.11184,76.29901],[-87.6,76.42],[-89.49068,76.47239],[-89.6161,76.95213],[-87.76739,77.17833],[-88.26,77.9],[-87.65,77.97022222222222],[-84.97634,77.53873],[-86.34,78.18],[-87.96192,78.37181],[-87.15198,78.75867],[-85.37868,78.9969],[-85.09495,79.34543],[-86.50734,79.73624],[-86.93179,80.25145],[-84.19844,80.20836],[-83.40869565217383,80.1],[-81.84823,80.46442],[-84.1,80.58],[-87.59895,80.51627],[-89.36663,80.85569],[-90.2,81.26],[-91.36786,81.5531],[-91.58702,81.89429],[-90.1,82.085],[-88.93227,82.11751],[-86.97024,82.27961],[-85.5,82.65227345805704],[-84.260005,82.6],[-83.18,82.32],[-82.42,82.86],[-81.1,83.02],[-79.30664,83.13056],[-76.25,83.1720588235294],[-75.71878,83.06404],[-72.83153,83.23324],[-70.665765,83.16978075838284],[-68.5,83.10632151676575]]]]}},
```

Comment: It doesn't help much because I should create a json file with all the coordinates of all the countries.

Comment: I could send you the file if you like? I have one with all the data in

Comment: yes, if you send it to me, thank you. One last question, how can I use the coordinate set of apis that I already use?

Comment: Here is the geojson file : [link](https://app.box.com/s/z3rc88qc295us9ec7u9ih1sllh17zir4)

What apis do you use?

Comment: The API is the following: https://restcountries.com/v2/all

Comment: I solved in this way : export const Map = ({lat,lng,area,nameCountry}) => {
 

  const key = lat + ':' + lng;

const country = countries.features.find((country) => country.properties.name === nameCountry);                   <GeoJSON 
        data={country} 
        style={{
          color: 'red',
          weight: 1,
          fillColor: 'red',
          fillOpacity: 0.1
        }} 
      />